# How to change hyperlink/button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In rails,I'm modifying a hyperlink to add a javascript variable using jQuery. It works when I use link_to but not when I use a hyperlink.

This code works:

```
<% url1 = game_path(@gameId)%>
<%= link_to "Go!", url1, :id => "my_link", :method => 'put' %>

<script>
function jquerySetup(){
var url = "";
var url = $('#my_link').attr('href') + '&message=' + gameWon;
$('#my_link').attr('href', url);
}
</script>
```

But this code does not:

```
<% url1 = game_path(@gameId)%>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href= <%= url1 %> id= "my_link" > Go! </a>

<script>
function jquerySetup(){
var url = "";
var url = $('#my_link').attr('href') + '&message=' + gameWon;
$('#my_link').attr('href', url);
}
</script>
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

is `<%= url1 %>` wrapped in quotes? if not, wrap it in quotes and your href should be specced properly.

Comment: No. But this part works. It does not add the message= gamewon when it does not work.

Comment: you sure it's not prevent id from being defined as 'my_link' ? can you provide the output of the html?